# Give example graph with specified properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Give an example of a graph G of order 6 and size 10 such that δ(G) = 3 and Δ(G) = 4�[image: Can I do like this??]

Comment: How are $δ(G)$ and $Δ(G)$ defined?

Comment: Do you want the definitions??

Comment: Yes thx, didn't know this notation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V=\{a,b,c,d,e,f \}$

$E=\{(a,d),(a,e),(a,f),(b,d),(b,e),(b,f),(c,d),(c,e),(c,f),(a,b) \}$

All vertices have degree $3$ except for $a$ and $b$ which have degree $4$.

Comment: Is this the graph in the picture?

Comment: @NoName No it is not.